# How to pass all items in list, through for loop, if iteration starts not from first element

Tags: language-agnostic, iteration

How to pass all items in list, through for loop. If iteration starts not from first element.

Lets jump to example right away:

**We have list** `['a','b','c','d']`.

*I want to go through all the items in this list using for loop. But if iteration starts not from first element, I want to came back oand start from first element.
Something like this:*

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d']

start_index = 2

for loop_num in range(len(lst)):
    item = lst[start_index+loop_num]
    print item
```

*It will print me:*

```
>> c,d
```

Than rises **IndexOutOfRange error**

*But I want result to be like this:*

```
>> c, d, a, b
```

*and if we change the `start_index` variable to `1` result suppose to be:*

```
b, c, d, a
```

*in case of `start_index = 0`*

*result:* `a, b, c, d`

Comment: "*But I want result to be like this:*" `>> c, b, a, b` -- do you mean `c, d, a, b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d']

start_index = 2

for loop_num in range(len(lst)):
    item = lst[(start_index+loop_num) % len(lst)]
    print item
```

% - it is special operation. 3 % 5 = 3, 10 % 5 = 0,
read about it [Remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) and [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#id27)

Answer (score 4):

### Python

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> def func(lst, idx=0):
...     for i in lst[idx:] + lst[:idx]: yield i
...
>>> list(func(l))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> list(func(l,2))
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
>>>
```

Uses standard Python list slicing syntax, one optional argument(`idx`) and [a generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%` to get the correct indices:

```
def rotated(lst, start=0):
    c = len(lst)
    for idx in xrange(c):
        yield lst[(idx + start) % c]


for x in rotated(['a','b','c','d'], 2):
    print x,
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer in C#. Let's say we have an array (easier to show) of size x. Starting index is y, and is smaller then x, but larger then 0.

```
int i;
for(i=y;i<x;i++)
{
  //do something with MyArray[i]¸
  if(i==x)
  {
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
      //do something with MyArray[i]
    }
    i=x;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby arrays have a method called `values_at` which takes an index, or a range of indices (combined, in any amount). `for` loops are hardly used - this is the first one I write.

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d']
start_index = 2

for v in lst.values_at(start_index..-1, 0...start_index)
  puts v
end
```